# New Breaker, Receptacle, and Plug for New Appliance

Tags: electrical

I'm wanting to use a 220v, 50Hz, 6000w Infrared Flash Dryer but don't have a way to power it currently... Additionally, the appliance comes without a plug... just 3 wires ready to be connected to a plug.

I've done some research and figured out that I should be using a 30amp breaker with #8 wire (it'll be more than 25ft from the box).

How do I know what receptacle and plug to use? I read that NEMA 10 is typically used for clothes dryers and stuff and that I should be looking at NEMA 14, but it has 4 prongs and the appliance only has 3 wires...

If you suggest NEMA 10, would it hurt to go with NEMA 14? If I were to use NEMA 14, would I ignore the ground or the neutral when adding the plug onto the appliance?

Comment: NEMA 10 is obsolete and dangerous. No ground!

Comment: Does this appliance have some sort of motor or motorized (mechanical) timer in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I've yet to receive the unit... all I have to go on currently is a recommendation for the device (reason for buying) and the Amazon link: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0875LMQFV/

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak to if the frequency will be a problem, but 240V plus ground is a NEMA 6. Do not use a NEMA 10, it is two hots and a neutral.

I don't believe a flash dryer operates at full current for 3+ hours, <strike>#10 and a 30A breaker should be fine</strike>, if it operates more than 3 hours at full current then #8 copper wire and a 40A breaker would be needed.

Edit: After good night's sleep and a cup of coffee I realized my answer at very least violated NEC 210.21 which limits cord connected loads on a 30A circuits to 24A, you would need to use #8 copper, a 40A breaker, and a NEMA 6-50 (or a NEMA 14-50 which would probably not satisfy a strict interpretation of (UL) Listing requirements of the cord cap to only install as the instructions describe and as tested by the testing agency, but (UL) is probably thrown out the window using a 50Hz appliance that has 50Hz sensors, timers or relays on 60Hz).

Comment: You said not to use NEMA 10, could I use NEMA 16 and just wire up 3 of the prongs on the plug? I feel like that'd be more future-friendly if I ever get another device I need to plug in.

Comment: @user1960364 -- one can use NEMA 14 and ignore the neutral, but the better plan is to run /3, cap the neutral off in the junction box, and fit a NEMA 6

Comment: @NoSparksPlease, so to summarize... I should get 8/3 solid copper, NEMA 6-50P, NEMA 6-50R, and a 40A breaker then cap the neutral in the just cap the neutral in the receptacle?

Comment: Yes, if you want to have a neutral for future modifications then you could cap it off in the junction box behind the receptacle.

Comment: I think the NEMA 14 *recep* is fine as long as you do provision a neutral from the panel to the recep.  So /3 cable.  A NEMA 14 *plug* is fine for an appliance that doesn't need all 4 wires, heck I recommend it for 120V/30A loads because NEMA 14-30s are lots of places.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, that was my initial thought... 14-30s seem to be a lot more common than 10s or even 6s... and simply not attaching the neutral for a device that doesn't require it seemed harmless to me. More flexibility in the future for plugging in other devices without having to swap out the recep. But I'm not an electrician, so I don't know what I might be overlooking and don't want to create a hazard.

Comment: I just searched Lowes and they don't even sell 6-50Rs... I'm going to have to buy one on Amazon or something.

Comment: I almost said this last comment but please, would you find a proper electrical supply house??? Big-box sucks (generally but especially for specialty) and Amazon is right out for a variety of reasons. These are easy problems for a proper electrical supply.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the smaller electrical supply stores are still closed... Anyway, I'm now left between choosing between 6-50s and 14-30s, any additional input? 